# How can I position text to the LEFT of a SurfaceCheckBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml

All:

I am working with XAML and WPF and have a SurfaceCheckBox. The default for a SurfaceCheckBox seems to keep the text on the right. Is there a way to put the text on the left?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add FlowDirection="RightToLeft" to the SurfaceCheckBox.

Here is an example:

```
<SurfaceCheckBox 
   Content="Text to display"
   FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
   IsChecked="True"
   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for! Thanks! Sometimes the code completion just does not give enough information for me to find what I need...

Comment: This works for a standard CheckBox too... which is awesome!! :)